# How to make "see through" text?

Tags: html, css

I have `body` with a `background-image` and a `div` with `background-color` as white.

I'm trying to make the text on that `div` (which is called `#content`) see through, so that the text is like a window to the background of the site.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: have you tried `opacity:.4` for example?

Comment: He wants the text to be see-through. You solutoin would only make the background more visible.

Comment: @KaiQing That won't work, see his example. CSS masking is the right way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is possible with CSS. With `background-clip: text`, you can use a background for the text but you will have to align it with the background of the page.

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  background: url(http://o.homedsgn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/NYC-at-Night-54.jpg) no-repeat;
  margin: 10px;
  background-position: center top;
}
h1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 83px;
  margin: 450px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
span {
  background: url(http://o.homedsgn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/NYC-at-Night-54.jpg) no-repeat;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display: block;
  background-position: center -450px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>NEW YORK</span></h1>
```

Comment: Are you sure `background-clip: text` is CSS3 and not a webkit extension? The [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#the-background-clip) doesn't list `text` as a possible value of `background-clip`.

Comment: `h1`'s `color` shouldn't be `transparent` because then the text becomes invisible on non-webkit browsers. And webkit browsers don't need it because they have `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent`.

Answer (score 2):

Try clipping for your #content, assign the same background file (needs to be repositioned eventually):

```
#content {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);  /* Fallback: assume this color ON TOP of image */
 background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: But I do see through your example what he was actually asking for, so plus one to that