# make text transparent with in div with black background but transparent text

Tags: html, css

i want to make a div with black background but the text should be transparent with red border. Any idea?

till now i have been able to make my text transparent but when i add background color to the div, it makes text background with the same color.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oo6cj7vb)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text">
    <h1>EXPERIENCES</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text h1 {

    font-size: 112px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;

}
```

Comment: this is what i have tried till now http://jsfiddle.net/oo6cj7vb/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make "see through" text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642359/how-to-make-see-through-text)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div { background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
      color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
      -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
      -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
      font-size:100px;
    }
```