# Set WPF Label Content Alpha Transparency instead of entire control Opacity

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, expression-blend

I am trying to Set a label's content to be invisible, so that I can overlay that on the content behind. For instance, the control's background is a solid color but, the text has a alpha transparency that allows me to see through the entire control (Like a photoshop trick). That way, dynamic content can be seen with a variable background. I apply this pattern with PNG files but, that obviously wont do when the content needs to change. A great example of this question (Since I am not very good at asking it) can be found here... but, of course, this is for css. ([How to make "see through" text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642359/how-to-make-see-through-text#)) Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: This was my own question for a while... "Masking out a text from a border's background" . There is a way to achieve this, but it doesn't involve using a Label. through code behind you can define an OpacityMask for a border removing the text.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I understand the use of opacitymask but, thus far my attempts to use it within this "UserControl" have been fruitless. I did just try it in the code behind to no avail. What are we placing within the border to achieve transparent text? TextBlock? I have tried a few combinations based on your suggestion but, still don't have much to show for it. :(

Comment: what I'm trying to say is that I'm sure we can render a textblock with a technique  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28626055/4805219) , if we could only modify the resulting BitmapSource objects pixels and invert their Alpha channel and set it as OpacityMask it would work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution to this thing...
The trick is to use **Clip** instead of OpacityMask.

First look at the layout:

```
<Grid Background="Red">
    <Border Background="White" Name="targetImage" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="200"/>

    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="render" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Here the grid with the red background can be used as your Background Image!
The border inside it covers it with the white color.
Then I put a button that removes the Text we want from border when pressed.

here is the code for button click event:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Typeface face = new Typeface("Candara");
        FormattedText tx = new FormattedText("Hello", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, face, 70, Brushes.Black);
        Geometry textGeom = tx.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));
        Rect boundingRect = new Rect(new Point(-100000, -100000), new Point(100000, 100000));
        RectangleGeometry boundingGeom = new RectangleGeometry(boundingRect);
        GeometryGroup group = new GeometryGroup();
        group.Children.Add(boundingGeom);
        group.Children.Add(textGeom);
        targetImage.Clip = group;   


    }
```

It's basically creating a text! then we need to invert the mask.
inverting is done using the help of **boundingRect** .

Edit: Almost forgot. You can put all this logic inside a User control. and run this code everytime the Text property of your Usercontrol changes.

have fun ;)

Comment: How in the world did you find an answer to that so quick? Genius! I was still flipping the logic in the Visual. I did that before with an OCR Screen capture and knew what that strategy involved. But, this is genius!! +200 :) Thanks so much, been at this for hours now! :P

Comment: downvote for using the exact same code and variable names as an answer dated 1 year earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27942156/2353523